# SBT: could not define task

Tags: scala, sbt

Here is my task. It should remove everything from war's lib besides swager jars.

```
packageCleanWar :=  {
  val war: File = (packageWar in Compile).value
  val tmpDir = target.value / "tmp"
  val warPath = war.getAbsolutePath
  val nf = (s: String) => s match {
    case s if s.startsWith("WEB-INF/lib/swagger") => true
    case s if s.startsWith("WEB-INF/lib/") => false
    case _ => true
  }
  IO.unzip(war, tmpDir, NameFilter.fnToNameFilter(nf))
  IO.delete(war)
  val newWar = new File(warPath)
  IO.zip(Path.allSubpaths(tmpDir), newWar)
  newWar
}
```

While trying to load it I receive the following

```
C:\work\project\server\build.sbt:55: error: not found: value packageCleanWar
packageCleanWar :=  {
^
[error] Type error in expression
```

allthough I define it in the same style that is mentioned [here](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.1/docs/Detailed-Topics/TaskInputs.html). What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare the task as well as define it:

```
lazy val packageCleanWar = taskKey[File]("packageCleanWar description")

packageCleanWar :=  {
  val war: File = (packageWar in Compile).value
  val tmpDir = target.value / "tmp"
  val warPath = war.getAbsolutePath
  val nf = (s: String) => s match {
    case s if s.startsWith("WEB-INF/lib/swagger") => true
    case s if s.startsWith("WEB-INF/lib/") => false
    case _ => true
  }
  IO.unzip(war, tmpDir, NameFilter.fnToNameFilter(nf))
  IO.delete(war)
  val newWar = new File(warPath)
  IO.zip(Path.allSubpaths(tmpDir), newWar)
  newWar
}
```

This is from [Tasks](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.1/docs/Detailed-Topics/Tasks.html).